# Using Google Sheets with Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-sheets, google-api

I'm trying to write a simple Dart/Flutter program. Actually I'm trying to include a feature on a more complicated one but since I've tried everything for two straight days and I'm starting to lose my mind I will settle for this.

Ideally my code would allow me to select a spreadsheet from the user's personal Google Sheets, read from it, create a new sheet and write some information on it.

Now if someone can show me how to create a spreadsheet on user's personal Google Sheets and write a simple value on A1 I'll be forever on debt to that person. It doesn't even need to show nothing on the screen. Just create that damn spreadsheet.

I've never use Google APIs before, so I'm probably doing something wrong, but I can't find out what it is.

- I want to read/write user's personal Sheets. So I'm using Client ID OAuth 2.0 from Google Developer Console.
- I've tried everything that I have been able to find here, and I'm starting to give up, that's the reason that I'm asking for a solution. A simple solution. I can work from that, but the posts saying "you should use XX package" haven't helped me with this problem.

Thanks

EDIT: My last try

```
import 'package:googleapis/sheets/v4.dart';
import "package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart" as auth;

void main() {

  var id = auth.ClientId(
      "...myID....apps.googleusercontent.com",  
      "...");
  var scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"];



  auth.clientViaUserConsent(id, scopes, prompt).then((auth.AuthClient client) {
    SheetsApi api = SheetsApi(client);
    //Here I'd do things, if I could
    client.close();
  });
}

void prompt(String url) {
  print("Please go to the following URL and grant access:");
  print("  => $url");
  print("");
}
```

I go to the URL, and grant access, but then I'm redirected to my localhost

Comment: Could you add code from one of your tries?

Comment: Of course. I've edited my previous post

Answer (score 0):

You just need to send a POST request to `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets` endpoint with a JSON representation of a spreadsheet for example:

```
{
  "spreadsheetId": string,
  "properties": {
    object (SpreadsheetProperties)
  },
  "sheets": [
    {
      object (Sheet)
    }
  ],
  "namedRanges": [
    {
      object (NamedRange)
    }
  ],
  "spreadsheetUrl": string,
  "developerMetadata": [
    {
      object (DeveloperMetadata)
    }
  ]
}
```

You can get more information on the official [google sheets API documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create).

If you want to start working in a project with spreadsheets manipulations, [googleapis](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis) package is a must.

Comment: That's a piece of code that I don't know how to mix with mine.
Could you further elaborate?

Comment: You don't need anything else, you have an endpoint and a request body. What are you looking for?

Comment: have you tried following the documentation on how to create a Spreadsheet first? In it, what is the part you do not really understand? Authorization? Making the request with dart? You can check that method and test it [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create).

Answer (score 0):

This code authenticates a user, creates a Google Sheet Spreadsheet named 'hello_spreadsheet' and writes some data to the first row of the spreadsheet. Code to authenticate Firebase is commented out.

```
    //import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
    import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
    import 'package:googleapis/drive/v3.dart' as drive;
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'package:googleapis/sheets/v4.dart' as sheets;
    
    myGoogleSheet() async {
      var authenticateClient = await signInWithGoogle();
      var sheetID = await createSpreadSheet(authenticateClient);
      writeToSheet(authenticateClient, sheetID);
    }
    
    Future signInWithGoogle() async {
      final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await GoogleSignIn(scopes: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
      ]).signIn();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
    
      //final GoogleAuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      //  accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      //  idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      //);
      //var auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
      //await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      final authHeaders = await googleUser.authHeaders;
      final authenticateClient = GoogleAuthClient(authHeaders);
      return authenticateClient;
    }
    
    Future createSpreadSheet(GoogleAuthClient authenticateClient) async {
      final driveApi = drive.DriveApi(authenticateClient);
      var driveFile = new drive.File();
      driveFile.name = "hello_spreadsheet";
      driveFile.mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet';
      final result = await driveApi.files.create(driveFile);
      return result.id;
    }
    
    writeToSheet(GoogleAuthClient authenticateClient, String sheetID) {
      final sheetsApi = sheets.SheetsApi(authenticateClient);
      sheets.ValueRange vr = new sheets.ValueRange.fromJson({
        "values": [
          ["2021/04/05", "via API", "5", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"]
        ]
      });
      sheetsApi.spreadsheets.values.append(vr, sheetID, 'A:J', valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED').then((sheets.AppendValuesResponse r) {
        print('append completed');
      });
    }
    
    class GoogleAuthClient extends http.BaseClient {
      final Map _headers;
      final http.Client _client = new http.Client();
      GoogleAuthClient(this._headers);
      Future send(http.BaseRequest request) {
        return _client.send(request..headers.addAll(_headers));
      }
    }
```